# Why is my program printing 0 instead of the intended value? (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a calculator program for my class (not fully completed as you can tell) and I'm running into a problem with the Multiplication and Division section. They both print out 0 instead of their intended value, but Addition and Subtraction work fine. Any help?

```
int choice = 8;
double numberone;
double numbertwo;
    
while(choice > 7 || choice < 1){
    printf("(1) Addition \n(2) Subtraction \n(3) Multiplication \n(4) Division \n(5) Modulus (integers only) \n(6) Test if prime (integers only) \n(7) Exit \nPlease choose an operation: \n");
    scanf(" %i", &choice);
    
    if (choice != 5 || choice!= 6){
        printf("Enter the first number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &numberone);
        
        printf("Enter the second number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &numbertwo);
        
        if (choice == 1){
            double sum = numberone + numbertwo;
            printf("Sum: %d", sum);
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            double dif = numberone - numbertwo;
            printf("Difference: %d", dif);
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            double pro = numberone * numbertwo;
            printf("Product: %d", pro);
        }
        else if (choice == 4){
            double quo = numberone / numbertwo;
            printf("Quotient: %d", quo);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: ans show the actual and expected input and output.

Comment: `(choice != 5 || choice!= 6)` will always be true. What do you intend here?

Comment: You need to use `%lf` format to read `double`, not `%d`.

Comment: What are the return values (not the scanned values) of all the scanf()a? shed the habit of ignoring them now.

Comment: You also need to use `%lf` in the `printf()` calls when printing the results.

Answer (score 1):

You use `%d` in your `printf` which converts your results to an Integer. Use `%lf` instead.

```c
// ...
        else if (choice == 3){
            double pro = numberone * numbertwo;
            printf("Product: %lf", pro);
        }
        else if (choice == 4){
            double quo = numberone / numbertwo;
            printf("Quotient: %lf", quo);
// ...
```

**EDIT**:
The same applies to your scanf. Use `%lf` instead of `%i`:

```c
// ...
       printf("Enter the first number: ");
       scanf(" %lf", &numberone);
        
       printf("Enter the second number: ");
       scanf(" %lf", &numbertwo);
// ...
```

Comment: He's also using `%d` in the `scanf`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh you're right. Thanks